# How to translate 我知道大概是怎么回事？

Tags: translation

我知道大概是怎么回事，但是能不能有人给我详细解释一下？

> I probably know what's going on, but can someone explain the details
> to me?

感觉probably know what's going on不是很准确的翻译`我知道大概是怎么回事`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, it is "what's going on", but without more context, I'd plump for "how it happened."

知道大概: have an inkling

我知道大概是怎么回事，
I have an inkling of how it happened,

但是能不能有人给我详细解释一下？
but could someone (please) give me a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 6):

我知道 - I know

**大概**是怎么回事 - **roughly** what happened

但是 but

能不能有人 can someone

给我详细解释一下？ detailedly explain it to me?

> 我知道大概是怎么回事，但是能不能有人给我详细解释一下？

> I know roughly what happened, but can someone explain it in detail to me?

Comment: Whether 大概 should be translated as "roughly" or "probably" really depends on the context, but since the second parts asks for 详细的解释, that shows that the intended meaning was "roughly" and not "probably". +1

Answer (score 1):

**get the gist**

> To understand the central, essential, or general matter of something,
> such as an argument, speech, concept, process, etc., without being
> proficient in the more specific details.

I get the gist of what's going on, but can someone explain it in greater detail to me?

Other possible answer: "Rough understanding"

Answer (score 0):

The reason you feel that the translation not very good is the problem with your word sequence: "I probably/roughly know" means you might not know, or, partly know. 半知半解
"I know roughly ..." as the previous answer is perfect. 一知半解   You do know, but not all of it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as offered actually is the best translation.

It's not uncommon for native English speakers to use a bit of uncertainty when making a claim to understand something.

"I probably know what's going on, but can someone explain it to me?"
Completely native, well spoken.

"I think I know what's up, but could someone break it down for me?"
Completely native, spiced up to sound cooler.

"I think I got the gist of it, but if someone could go over the details..."
Completely native, maybe a little more UK in tone.

The "I have an inkling of an understanding" is a bit off because that emphasizes, a bit unnaturally, that you mostly do not understand. That would be more like saying 我有一点点明白;as an inkling of something is like a small hint of it.

I'm a native, American English speaker and taught adult spoken English in Tianjin for about 7 years.

Answer (score -1):

Agree with last two comments

> The answer as offered actually is the best translation.

Just one more thing... In both English and Chinese, the speaker uses the verb `know`, but then continues to ask to `explain`. It reminds me that knowing and understanding can be two very different things in other verb centric languages. :)